# for loop giving warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

Tags: c

I've been staring at this for ages and can't figure out why it's giving me a warning at the for-loop statement.

```
//looks for a certain account by name in the provided list, return index 
//of account if found, else -1

int AccountSearch(BankArray bank, char name[100])
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i ; i < maxAccounts ; i++)
    {
        /* if this index contains the given value, return the index */
        if (strcmp(bank->list[i]->accountName, name) == 0)
        { 
            return i;
        }
    }

    /* if we went through the entire list and didn't find the 
     * value, then return -1 signifying that the value wasn't found
     */
    return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first expression in your `for` loop is not used and it's equivalent to writing

```
i;
```

change it to

```
for (; i < maxAccounts ; ++i)
```

or better, since it's only executed the very first time the loop is found, use it to initialize and declare `i`, like this

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < maxAccounts ; ++i)
```